# Argo cd with eks fargate

Tags: kubernetes, aws-fargate, argocd, argo-workflows, gitops

Is there anyone who uses argo cd on eks fargate?? It seems that there is an issue with Argo setup on Fargate. All pods are in `pending state`

I’ve tried installing on argocd namespace and existing ones. Still doesn’t work

I tried to install it using the commands below:

```
kubectl create namespace argocd
kubectl apply -n argocd -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-cd/v2.4.7/manifests/install.yaml
```

Comment: Why are the pods in `pending` state? What does `kubectl -n argocd get events` tell you?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have created a fargate profile with the namespace selector as `argocd`. It might be one of the issues.

refer this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate-getting-started.html#fargate-gs-create-profile